# Is it possible in C++11 / 14 syntax to write an lambda function which will see parent variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

in abstraction:

```
int i = 1;
auto go = [] () {
    return i;
};
```

Is it possible to make something like that in modern C++ syntax?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Formally speaking, the ability to access the surrounding context is the key difference between a *function* (which cannot) and a *closure* (which can). Depending on the languages this *capture* of the *environment* may occur via copy or reference.

In C++11 (and beyond), lambdas are *closures* and as usual with C++ we have a fine-grained way of specifying *how* the capture is done:

- by copy: implicitly `[=]() { return i; }` or explicitly `[i]() { return i; }`
- by reference: implicitly `[&]() { return i; }` or explicitly `[&i]() { return i; }`

and C++14 even introduces *generalized lambda captures*, so you can capture:

- by move: existing variable `[i = std::move(i)]() { return i; }`
- or create a new variable `[i = 1]() { return i; }`

The square brackets delimit the capture list.

Comment: Technically, the `std::move` version also creates a new variable (as does any capture, if you wanna get pedantic). Also, I wouldn't special-case it to those two forms - _generalized lambda captures_ can be initialized with anything.

Comment: @Xeo: the interesting part in `std::move`, for me, is the reuse of the same "name" for the identifier, even though conceptually the `i` in `std::move(i)` is from outside and `i` from `i =` is inside. I'll try to word it differently.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, depends on whether you want to capture it by value:

```
auto go = [i] () {
    return i;
};
```

Or by reference:

```
auto go = [&i] () {
    return i;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put it in the capture section:

```
auto go = [i] () {
   return i;
};
```